# How to implement queues using linux kernel list?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linked-list, queue

I need to write some functions in C using Linux Kernel Lists to manipulate queues. The first task to do is insert a node pointed by p, into the queue knowing the list_head is q. So we define function like:

```
void insertProcQ(struct list_head *q, struct proc *p)
```

proc is also defined by linux kernel lists.
and here is a part of list.h I need to use as the queue implementation:

```
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};    
static inline void INIT_LIST_HEAD(struct list_head *list)
    {
        list->next = list;
        list->prev = list;
    }
```

I know how to insert a node to a queue, but I'm little confused about how to do it using kernel lists. So, any tips or same examples would be appreciated.

Comment: A list is a list is a list... And it's not like there's not thousands of example on using the implementation used in the Linux kernel in the Linux kernel.

Comment: If you try to write a new code then look at kfifo which is queue API in Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `list_add` example in following link
https://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/

Assuming p has `struct list_head list` member.
This is how your code will look like

```
 void insertProcQ(struct list_head *q, struct proc *p)
 {
        list_add(&(p->list), q);
 }
```

Comment: It was exactly what I need. Specially the commented `list.h` file: https://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/list.h because I had the file without any comments.

Comment: Looks like copy from LDDv3. Inner parentheses are redundant.

Comment: Copied from the link :)